# bundle open disqus_api not accessing real source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-2.3

I'm trying out the gem https://github.com/toptal/disqus_api for use on [this project](https://github.com/Arepo/rails-blog), but struggling to get it to accept my auth details. That might end up being a separate question, but for now I wanted to explore the source code and do some manual debugging.

The trouble is, something odd is happening when I `bundle open disqus_api`. It's seemingly finding the files, but when I make any change to them (eg a interrupting with a debugger), it's not being picked up (and when it raises an error that should consequently be shifted a line down, the line number is unchanged).

That said, one sign that I might not be in completely the wrong place is that when I temporarily delete the gem's entire lib directory, while it still loads the core DisqusApi class, pry's 'show-source' method on the class now outputs `Error: Couldn't locate a definition for DisqusApi!`.

(Edited to add):

To be specific, it's line 70 of [this file](https://github.com/toptal/disqus_api/blob/master/lib/disqus_api/api.rb)

So after I've edited it, we have:

```
def perform_request #line 68
  require 'byebug' #69
  byebug #70
  yield.tap do |response| #71
    raise InvalidApiRequestError.new(response) if response['code'] != 0 #72
  end
end
```

But it errs like this:
`DisqusApi::InvalidApiRequestError: {"code"=>5, "response"=>"Invalid API key"}
from /Users/sashacooper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/disqus_api-0.0.5/lib/disqus_api/api.rb:70:in`block in perform_request'`

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **byebug** gem

1. On your project's **Gemfile.rb**

   ```
   group :development do
     gem 'byebug'
   end
   ```
2. On the terminal **open the disqus_api** gem

   ```
   bundle open disqus_api
   ```
3. On the gem's [lib/disqus_api.rb](https://github.com/toptal/disqus_api/blob/master/lib/disqus_api.rb) require the byebug gem.

   ```
   require 'byebug'
   ```
4. Place your `debugger` call on the line you want to debug

Comment: That's what I meant by trying a debugger break (edited the OP to clarify) - it's not tripping the debugger.

Comment: Are you sure you followed all the steps, specially step #3?

Comment: Certain. It's what I was trying to do in the first place (and since I put the require and debugger statements on the line immediately before, the line number of the error message would have changed). So for some reason I guess this isn't the code that's being run.

Comment: I've added some more info to the OP.

Comment: Try requiring byebug on [lib/disqus.rb](https://github.com/toptal/disqus_api/blob/master/lib/disqus_api.rb) after line 14, and then placing a debugger on that same file after line 35.

Comment: I believe the error happens before the program reaches the line in which you were placing your debugger call, so it never gets to execute it.

Comment: If that's the case, please open another question so we can take care of configuring the disqus_api gem correctly :)

Comment: You're right. I still don't know why it wasn't tripping that line (or acknowledging changes to the file), but putting the debugger earlier worked ok. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! Would you mind accepting the answer?